# How to do neat geometric illustration?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, education

I would like to know how to do neat illustration for geometric concept such as this one : [image]
This image come from "DoCarmo - Differential geometry of curve and surfaces, p41" and is an illustration of the covariant derivative defined on a regular surface S.

I would like answer to such questions :

- Do I need to use Geogebra or a software such as Photoshop to reach such a result ?
- Do I need to find parametrization to all of these object or instead, draw them like on a sheet of paper but on a specific software ?
- How much time do it usually take to a mathematician to create its illustration ?
- ...

I will be also very grateful of some tips. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Mathematical illustration is an art. It takes an artist to do it well. See the wonderful illustrations in the book Geometry and the Imagination by Hilbert and Cohn-Vossen.

Comment: Do you mean that geometers "engage" artists to do their mathematical illustrations ?

Comment: I mean that the best mathematical illustrations come from a collaboration between mathematicians and artists.

Comment: If you want a textbook quality result I would use TikZ.

Comment: Yes, I use TikZ [part of TexLive]

Comment: I did all the artwork for my four textbooks using Mathematica and Adobe Illustrator. I am very upset that my copy of Illustrator no longer runs on my computer and now one must buy a monthly license — which I refuse to do. I will eventually learn to use Inkscape, I guess.

Comment: Lots of discussion and ideas here: https://twitter.com/keenanisalive/status/1453771939818921998